# Android AsyncTask synchronized

Tags: android, asynchronous

How the following method will be executed?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   super.oncReate(bundle);
   printInfoFromServer();
}

private synchronized void printFromServer()
{
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){ doInBackground../// }.execute(null, null, null);
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){ doInBackground../// }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

The `asynchronus` request will be executed in serial or paralel?

Comment: Threads will execute parallelly as none of them is waiting for another...

Comment: paralel,cause printFromServer is just new a object.just like new anonymous  Thread.then there's thread will do their work parallel.

Comment: use a executor for parallel execution